# Why is code formatting not working on this code?

Tags: bug, code-formatting, formatting

I am trying to edit an answer to format the following piece of code. 
[How to fetch text value from a popup window when it appears?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52766038/how-to-fetch-text-value-from-a-popup-window-when-it-appears#52766038)

It somehow isn't appearing in the edit.

```
<div class="talk-button animated slideInUp in">
    <a type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#chapelModal">
    <span class="hidden">Would you like to talk to us about this article? 
    </span></a>  
</div>
```

It seems to be working here

Comment: You've got to put a break between the list and the code. `<?-- -->` would work.

Comment: Or indent the code 4 *more* spaces

Comment: Come on guys! That grammar of separating sentences into an ordered list is atrocious. It should be read as a text. It's not a step by step guide.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've got to put a break between the list and the code such as `<?-- -->`, or indent the code *4 more spaces*. The first makes for a separate code block, while the second creates a code block that is part of the list element.

Way 1 using `<?-- -->`:

- list
- here

```
public void code() {
    goesHere();
}
```

Image of what the edit looks like:

[image]

---

or Way 2, indenting 8:

- list
- here

  ```
  public void code() {
      goesHere();
  }
  ```

Image of what the edit looks like::

[image]

Comment: but where is list in the code snippet?

Comment: @PavanAndhukuri: it's in the **question** above where you're adding the list, and that list is messing up the code formatting below it

Comment: Using jpeg for text? Blasphemy!

Answer (score 6):

You have to add extra indentation when you're putting code right after a list item. I edited the post for you, and now the code shows up.